# how to ask wsdl for not having problems with parsing in apex code?

Tags: apex, integration, webservices

I'm waiting wsdl from external system to generate apex code from WSDL and realize an integration with salesforce. towards this system I will have to implement two flows from salesforce. Those flows have the same data but one has the same data as the other plus other fields.
example:

1. sendCards: name, surname, code
2. sendChannel: name, surname, code, channel

How should I ask for the wsdl?

- only one request and two operations?
- two requests each with a single operation
- a single request and single operation and a tag indicating the type of data I am sending (string "channel" or "card")

I wouldn't have problem when parse wsdl

Comment: FYI, assuming the external system supports JSON, you are less likely to run into a blocking problem by using a JSON API than a WSDL one. Apex has good support for [HTTP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm) and [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm).